# Is Keras thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, keras

I'm using Python and Keras (currently using Theano backend, but I have no qualms with switching). I have a neural network that I load and process multiple sources of information with in parallel. Currently, I've been running each one in a separate process and it loads its own copy of the network from the file. This seems like a waste of RAM, so I was thinking it would be more efficient to have a single multi-threaded process with one instance of the network that is used by all threads. However, I'm wondering if Keras is thread safe with either backend. If I run `.predict(x)` on two different inputs at the same time in different threads, will I run into race conditions or other issues?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to quote the kind [fcholet](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/13116):

> _make_predict_function is a private API. We should not recommend calling it.
>
> Here, the user should simply call predict first.
>
> Note that Keras models can't be guaranteed to be thread-safe. 
>   Consider having independent copies of the model in each thread 
>   for CPU inference.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, Keras is thread safe, if you pay a little attention to it.

In fact, in reinforcement learning there is an algorithm called [Asynchronous Advantage Actor Critics (A3C)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01783.pdf) where each agent relies on the same neural network to tell them what they should do in a given state. In other words, each thread calls `model.predict` concurrently as in your problem. An example implementation with Keras of it is [here](https://github.com/jaara/AI-blog/blob/master/CartPole-A3C.py).

You should, however, pay extra attention to this line if you looked into the code:
`model._make_predict_function() # have to initialize before threading`

This is never mentioned in the Keras docs, but its necessary to make it work concurrently. In short, `_make_predict_function` is a function that compiles the `predict` function. In multi thread setting, you have to manually call this function to compile `predict` in advance, otherwise the `predict` function will not be compiled until you run it the first time, which will be problematic when many threading calling it at once. You can see a detailed explanation [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/6124).

I have not met any other issues with multi threading in Keras till now.

Comment: I think that the answer by Daniel is more accurate and up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75606666/5426539

Copying/cloning the model before calling the `predict()` method works.

```py
model = ...
_model = tensorflow.keras.models.clone_model(model)
predictions = _model.predict(...)
```