# Keras, TensorFlow : "TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use keras fune-tuning to develop image classify applications.
I deployed that application to a web server and the image classification is succeeded.

However, when the application is used from two or more computers at the same time, the following error message appears and the application doesn't work.

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.

Here is my code for image classification.

```
img_height, img_width = 224, 224
channels = 3

input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, channels))
vgg19 = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)

fc = Sequential()
fc.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg19.output_shape[1:]))
fc.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
fc.add(Dropout(0.5))
fc.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model = Model(inputs=vgg19.input, outputs=fc(vgg19.output))

model.load_weights({h5_file_path})

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

img = image.load_img({image_file_path}, target_size=(img_height, img_width))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = x / 255.0

pred = model.predict(x)[0]
```

How can I run this application in multiple computers at the same time?

Thank you for reading this post.

Comment: May be consider the solution for this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850089/is-keras-thread-safe] question

Comment: @Mitiku Thank you so much! It must be the information that I wanted. I'll try it.

Answer (score 13):

I found that there are a couple of workarounds, depending on various context:

1. **Using `clear_session()` function**:

   ```
   from keras import backend as K
   ```

   Then do following at the beginning or at the end of the function, after predicting all the data:

   ```
   K.clear_session()
   ```
2. **Calling `_make_predict_function()`**:

   After you load your trained model call:

   ```
   model._make_predict_function()
   ```

   See [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43393252/5715870)
3. **Disable threading:**

   If you are running django server use this command:

   ```
   python manage.py runserver --nothreading
   ```

   For flask use this:

   ```
   flask run --without-threads
   ```

If none of the above solutions work, check these links [keras issue#6462](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6462), [keras issue#2397](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2397)

Comment: I had this issue. I did run my model inside django app.  Running app without threads solved this issue.

Comment: Running server threadless isn't a solution! Thats a hack of the worst denomination

Comment: K.clear_session() helped me run load_model() successfully. Thanks!

Comment: K.clear_session() also helped me. thank you for your nice explanation