# Tensorflow : TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, fpga

I am trying to train a Transfer Learning model using VGG-16 on Tensorflow and generate the inference graph in order to do inference on a Xilinx Alveo FPGA card (using Visis AI platform like so https://github.com/Xilinx/Vitis-AI-Tutorials/blob/MNIST-Classification-TensorFlow/files/train.py).

I successfuly train the model but I am unable to generate the inference graph. Here's the error :

```py
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("vgg_base/Placeholder:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32) is not an element of this graph.
```

I have tried looking at this : [Tensorflow: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40785224/tensorflow-cannot-interpret-feed-dict-key-as-tensor) and this [Keras, TensorFlow : "TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51588186/keras-tensorflow-typeerror-cannot-interpret-feed-dict-key-as-tensor) but it's not working.

Here's my model definition :

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, applications

def customVGG(vgg_in, is_training):
 
    with tf.variable_scope('vgg_base'):
        base_model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16(
                weights='imagenet',
                input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
                include_top=False)

        # Freeze base model
        for layer in base_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False

        # Create new model on top.
        inputs = tf.keras.Input(tensor=vgg_in)
        x = base_model(inputs, training=False)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc"):
        x = tf.layers.flatten(x)
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=128, activation=tf.nn.relu, trainable=is_training, name='fc1')    

    # Finally add a 2 dense layer for class predictions
    with tf.variable_scope("Prediction"):
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=2, trainable=is_training, name='predictions')

        return x
```

Here's the code used to generate the inference graph:

```py
#####################################################
# Write out a graph for inference
#####################################################
# we cannot use the training graph for deployment
# we need to create a new graph with is_training set to False to disable dropout & batch norm
# this new graph does not have any nodes associated with training (loss, optimizer, etc)


with tf.Graph().as_default():

    # define placeholders for the input data
    x_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None,input_height,input_width,input_chan], name='images_in')

    # call the miniVGGNet function with is_training=False
    logits_1 = customVGG(vgg_in=x_1, is_training=False)

    tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(), INFER_GRAPH_DIR, INFER_GRAPH_FILENAME, as_text=False)
    print(' Saved binary inference graph to %s' % infer_graph_path)
    

    print('\nFINISHED')
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that you used to generate Inference Graph so that we can try to help you? Thanks!